# call to item versions endpoint

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-bim360

```
        var request = new RestRequest($"data/v1/projects/{projectId}/items/{itemId}/versions", Method.GET);
```

When making a call to this endpoint, we sometimes see files that don't have a createUserId or a lastModifiedUserId in the attributes object. We had assumed that one of these fields would always contain a value.

Is there a rule that governs if a file has a last modified user id or a create user Id I.e. if the file has been created using your API then it might have a created by id of null or empty?